# How To populate All Columns In ListView Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am getting data from `mysql database` through `php`, I fetching both values but the adapter is displaying only one.

This is my android `getData()` function which is getting one column now I want to get the second column which i am not getting

```
public void getdata(){
    try {
        URL url=new URL(retri_url);
        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            IS=new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(IS));

        StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");    
        }
        IS.close();
       result=stringBuilder.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject jsonObject=null;
        data=new String[jsonArray.length()];

        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

            jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            int id=Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.get("id").toString());
            String strI = String.valueOf(id);
            data[i] =strI;
            data[i]=jsonObject.getString("Name");    
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
}
```

Comment: because you are only fetching one column `Address` in string array , use POJO classes

Comment: can you give me an example please

Comment: @PavneetSingh I have edited the code please check only one column is fetching.. not all columns are not working!

Comment: post your response

Comment: i am getting only one column but there is no error in the log cat

Comment: please follow my previous comment and show what `result` look like

Comment: can you please make an answer so that i can run the code

Comment: put this `result` into Log or toast and show the values it containing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132637/discussion-between-tayyab-developer-and-pavneet-singh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the code is over writing data of `names` over `id` using a single array `data` here

```
data[i] =strI;
data[i]=jsonObject.getString("Name");
```

I suggest to move on to customize adapter but as requested a quick fix , here is the solution

1.) Create three arrays

```
String[] names, data;
//        ^^        to store names        
//              ^^  to store re-presentable data like "pavneet   2122"  
int[] id ;
//   ^^  to store ids
```

2.) Initialize arrays

```
data=new String[jsonArray.length()];
names=new String[jsonArray.length()];
id=new int[jsonArray.length()];
```

3.) Use `optInt` or `optString` , will handle the parsing for you

```
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject jsonObject=null;
data=new String[jsonArray.length()];
names=new String[jsonArray.length()];
id=new int[jsonArray.length()];

for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

 jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    id[i]=jsonObject.optInt("id");
    name[i]=jsonObject.optString("Name");
    data[i]=id[i]+"\t\t"+name[i];
```

Note : `\t\t` is for tab space so you can use `\n` for two line formatting

and you can use this `data[i]=name[i]+"\t\t"+id[i];` to display name and id
`